# Query builder cannot associate with category entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have 2 entities, MyItem and MyItemCategory. When I try to create a query with query builder I get the following error:

```
Error: Class App\Entity\MyItem has no
    field or association named myitem_category_id (500 Internal Server Error)
```

This is the where part of my query builder:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('App\Entity\MyItem')
        ->createQueryBuilder('m');

// adds where for category_id:
$queryBuilder->where('m.myitem_category_id = :category_id')->setParameter('category_id',$category_id);
```

Here're first entities:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyItemCategory")
 * @JoinColumn(name="myitem_category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $myItemCategory;
```

...and my category entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MyItem", mappedBy="myItemCategory")
 */
private $myItemCategories;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The querybuilder actually doesn't care about database fields, but instead uses the object mapper, so there is no field `my_item_category_id` on your *Entity*, but instead a field `myItemCategory`

So, you can either do:

```
$querybuilder
    ->where('m.myItemCategory = :category')
    ->setParameter('category', $category) // <-- an actual MyItemCategory object
```

or you can join it in and check for the id:

```
$querybuilder
    ->leftJoin('m.myItemCategory', 'mic')
    ->where('mic.id = :micid')
    ->setParameter('micid', $category_id)
```

(I actually don't know if `m.myItemCategory.id = :micid` might work ........ you could try ;o))